# GraphView - I cannot see my design

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have a Problem with GraphView. I can't see my design in my Activity_main. Instead design I see the following sentence "GraphView: No preview available "

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...
dependencies {
   ...
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
}
```

for helping

Mathiew

Comment: try building your project once

Comment: Generally, for third party views, there is no preview

Comment: What would you expect in that preview?

Answer (score 0):

For getting results, add some values in the graph.

Comment: give more information please

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31223826)